# AS3 (ActionScript 3), Tabbing 3 Times before Switching Fields

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, input, tabbing

It always comes as a surprise to me when I google a problem I am having and I am completely unable to find anything similar. In fact, the only 1 post that i found that describes the same problem can be found here: [Tabbing between fields - where does the cursor disappear to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014078/tabbing-between-fields-where-does-the-cursor-disappear-to)

That question got no responses unfortunately, and I am having the same exact issue.
The only major difference is, I'm using Classic Text instead of TLF Text.

My Form is setup on as3 w/ 2 input fields. the first has tabIndex set to 0, and the second has it set to 1. When i hit tab, the cursor vanishes. If i press it 2 more times, it finally shows up.

I placed the code below to observe what was happening:

```
var iox = function() {
trace(_root.stage.focus);

if (_root.stage.focus != null) {
    trace(_root.stage.focus.parent.name)
}

setTimeout(iox, 400);
}

iox();
```

I expected to see maybe other fields file that might've been hidden getting the focus or some other object.. But turns out that the only 2 objects that get the focus are indeed my input boxes. After typing into 1 field, pressing tab only once switches the focus to the other field. However, the blinking cursor indicator, as well as the ability to type text into the field only shows up after the third time the button is pressed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging and some trial and error I've managed to fix the problem.
Basically all i had to do was import the FocusManager class and activate it. The triple tabbing button just vanished after that.

```
import fl.managers.FocusManager;
var fm = new FocusManager(myclip);
myclip.txt1.tabIndex = 0;
myclip.txt2.tabIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your other items on display list have `tabEnabled` property set to true. [TabEnabled property description](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabEnabled) MCs with `buttonMode` set to true have this enabled. Apparently there are two objects with this setting in the list when you check. So either perform a manual check, or do the complete displaylist walk querying at least class name and `name` property of any object that has `tabEnabled` as true.